# Mule 3.5.0 - How to run flows in sequence

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-flow

I have two flows in my Mule application that I wish to run in sequence in order to try and achieve the following:

1. First flow reads information from a file and creates rows in a database
2. Second flow reads information from a different file and updates rows in the same database

Both files are dropped in the same location at the same time. Is there a simple way in Mule I can restrict the second flow from running until the first has completed? I'm very new to Mule so please excuse the potentially novice question! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a filter on the file inbound endpoint of the first flow so it picks only the file intended for itself, not the files for the second flow.
- At the end of the first flow, flow-ref the second flow.
- Make sure the first flow executes synchronously otherwise the JDBC operation in it may happen after the call to the second flow.
- In the second flow, use the [requester module](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introducing-mule-requester) to retrieve the second file.
- Process it...