# Mule 3.5.0 - Can you move a file to a directory when using the Mule Requestor module?

Tags: file, mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-flow

I'm using a [Mule Requester module](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester) in my flow to retrieve a csv file from an input folder and insert it's contents into a JDBC database. Is there a way I can move this file to another directory once it has been processed (in the same way a file endpoint can)? Currently the file is deleted and I'm thrown errors when I try to use the autoDelete and moveToDirectory attributes in my mulerequester tag. Including the mulerequestor tag for reference:

```
<mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="file://..." doc:name="File Requester"/>
```

Also - using a file endpoint rather than the requester isn't an option in this case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this:

- Configure a second file connector that has the `moveToDirectory` attribute set to wherever your files need to be moved.
- Use it explicitly in the requester:

  ```
  <mulerequester:request
       config-ref="Mule_Requester"
       resource="file://...?connector=movingConnector"
       doc:name="File Requester"/>
  ```
- Configure any other file inbound endpoints to explicitly use the other pre-existing connector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DavidDossot, I'm a little unsure as to where in my flow (and how) I should configure this second file connector, could you advise? This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912374/mule-3-5-0-how-to-run-flows-in-sequence) describes the context in which I'm using the requester. Thanks

Comment: Not in any the flow, in the Mule config. See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Transport+Reference